# Getting a new unique number for a column in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm creating an online payment system. The bank requires a unique invoice number. Suppose this is the table:

```
public class OnlinePaymentInfo
{
    public OnlinePaymentInfo()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Order FirstOrder { get; set; }
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string TransactionReferenceId { get; set; }
}
```

Now an order might change. Once it does I can't just send the payment info with the same invoice id to the bank for online payment. I want to get a new unique invoice ID. I can query the database for getting the maximum number, like this:

```
var newId = db.OnlinePayments.Max(op => op.InvoiceNumber) + 1;
```

But I'm wondering if this is the best way to do this.

Comment: Whatever your underlying database is - try to use a database-given mechanism - `IDENTITY` in SQL Server, `SEQUENCE` in Oracle (or SQL Server) - those are reliable and will work under load, too. Your `MAX()+1`  approach **will break** under load and will produce **duplicates** - don't do this! You're just wasting your time ....

Comment: If you were going to do that, you need to create a lock when you do, because you want to ensure you don't get duplicates.

Comment: Why you don't use `IDENTITY` key, If you use database-given mechanism given code will be unique.

Comment: The missing piece to the previous comments is that you would need to somehow void the existing invoice and create an entirely new invoice record.  I would definitely recommend this approach as it preserves a history of changes.

Comment: @marc_s I wanted to use `IDENTITY` and I've used it before. But the problem I'm facing is, I want to modify table. As far as I know, it will only update whenever a new record is being added to the table. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SamAxe As I mentioned in previous comment, I'm looking to update this column when I modify its content. Will that work in Entity Framework if I set it to `0`?

Comment: If you retrospectively change an invoice, the only legal way to do it (in the US and UK) is to create a Credit Note backing out the invoice, and then creating a new invoice with the correct amounts. Since they are legal documents, once you've sent one out it can't be changed as you please.

Comment: @simonatrcl I'm not facing a legal issue but I want to do this the right way of course. Suppose there's an `Order` table which has a foreign key to the `OnlinePaymentInfo`. Now if I change the `Order`'s Items (which is a list of `OrderItem`), what should I do? Should I create another `OnlinePaymentInfo`? And set it to that `Order` or create a whole new `Order`?

Comment: In the UK, you would not send out an invoice until the order has despatched. If the order changes after despatch what you do depends on why it changes. What you do depends on that, but if you've send a payment request to the bank, any changes have be new requests calculated to get to the right total. This might be sending a request with the negative of the original to effectively cancel it, and then another with the correct amount, or just a new one with a value to make the two add up to the correct amount.